# Button.grid() not working properly in pycharm tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, pycharm

I have a code that has to stack buttons, which looks like this:

```
b1 = Button(wn, text='1', command=do_smth)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
b2 = Button(wn, text='2', command=do_smth)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
b3 = Button(wn, text='3', command=do_smth)
b3.grid(row=0, column=2)
b4 = Button(wn, text='4', command=do_smth)
b4.grid(row=1, column=0)
b5 = Button(wn, text='5', command=do_smth)
b5.grid(row=1, column=1)
b6 = Button(wn, text='6', command=do_smth)
b6.grid(row=1, column=2)
b7 = Button(wn, text='7', command=do_smth)
b7.grid(row=2, column=0)
b8 = Button(wn, text='8', command=do_smth)
b8.grid(row=2, column=1)
b9 = Button(wn, text='9', command=do_smth)
b9.grid(row=2, column=2)
b0 = Button(wn, text='0', command=do_smth)
b0.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

I expectet the buttons to just place normally, but instead I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NUSROH AHEL\progs\calculator\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)
  File "C:\Users\AlexKh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2485, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

Can somebody please help?

*(Made in Pycharm Community Edition 2022.2.2)*

Comment: Your error doesn't match the code and the code is not runnable. Please post a [mre]

Comment: It worked for me. Do you have any other pack() or place()?

Comment: Thx, I already fixed it

Comment: I had pack on the Label, but now I use grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pack` in the other part of the text, just replace it with `grid`

Answer (score 0):

There follow the correct way to solve your trouble:

```
from tkinter import *

def do_smth():
    print("Botão pressionado!")

wn = Tk()

b1 = Button(wn, text='1', command=do_smth)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = Button(wn, text='2', command=do_smth)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

b3 = Button(wn, text='3', command=do_smth)
b3.grid(row=0, column=2)

b4 = Button(wn, text='4', command=do_smth)
b4.grid(row=1, column=0)

b5 = Button(wn, text='5', command=do_smth)
b5.grid(row=1, column=1)

b6 = Button(wn, text='6', command=do_smth)
b6.grid(row=1, column=2)

b7 = Button(wn, text='7', command=do_smth)
b7.grid(row=2, column=0)

b8 = Button(wn, text='8', command=do_smth)
b8.grid(row=2, column=1)

b9 = Button(wn, text='9', command=do_smth)
b9.grid(row=2, column=2)

b0 = Button(wn, text='0', command=do_smth)
b0.grid(row=3, column=1)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).